# Bootstrap 3 .row alignment with Sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, row

I've a full width page with sidebar and content areas. I need sidebar with fixed width value and the content areas width is rest of the page. As you can see on bootply example the second row goes under my sidebar which should not.

If I change .row:before, .row:after{display: table;} to table-cell, this problem looks solved however this is not a proper solution because it causes some other problems.

http://bootply.com/89133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the main content in it's own section (or div or content, whichever) and then position the two main elements absolutely. That should work. Take a look (updated):

http://bootply.com/89155

```
<div class="container">
<aside>MENU SIDEBAR</aside>
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">FULL WIDTH BOX</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">FULL WIDTH BOX</div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

css:

```
aside{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 500px; 
  background: red; 
  float: left;
}
section{ 
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  right: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I need sidebar with fixed width value and the content areas width is rest of the page. I can use pull-left and remove the margin and calculate the width with javascript but that's heavy and last option.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, should have seen that. I've updated my code example, hopefully that will work for you!