# Bootstrap Row Clearfix Interferes with floating sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a webpage that is full width with a fixed size left column. In some pages on the right of the column in the main area I want to use a bootstrap container with rows for alignment. However, after the first row, all subsequent content gets moved to the left of the full height sidebar, because the rows end with a clearfix.

Is there any sensible way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I just found the perfect answer:

[Bootstrap 3 .row alignment with Sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503518/bootstrap-3-row-alignment-with-sidebar)

For those who need it, the key is to not float the sidebar, but position it absolutely- as well as the content. Then use margins. This means that the container rows will not interfere with the left content, as it's not floated.